# Riemann integrability on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let's say  $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$  is a bounded function. Let's say that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ for every $a$ in $]-1,0[$ and every $b$ in $]0,1[$. Can we conclude that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[-1,1]$?

I was first looking for a counter example.
I see that the critical points are $-1,$ $1,$ and $0.$
I was looking for something with more than one discontinuity point because then it's not Riemann integrable.

I don't really see a counter example can someone maybe give me a hint.

Edit:
Because of the information I get in the reaction I'm no longer looking for a counter example but I'm trying to prove that $f$  is Riemann integrable over [-1,1].
Now I tried to prove that the lower sum equals the upper sum, because that's a basic definition for Riemann integrability but I'm a little bit confused because we don't have a concrete function. Maybe someone can suggest another way for a proof?

Comment: yes i will write it down

Comment: This is easy to answer if you know the characterization that a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of points where it is discontinuous has measure zero. Adding three more points of possible discontinuity (-1, 0, and 1) won't affect this.

Comment: wait, I don't think i understand. So you say that in this case f isn't riemannintegrable because you can find an example that is discontinue in zero or?

Comment: No, I'm saying that $f$ is Riemann integrable on every $[a,b]$ with $-1 < a < 0 < b < 1$, which means that $f$ is continuous at almost every point in $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$ (i.e. everywhere in these intervals except possibly a set of measure zero). Therefore $f$ is continuous at almost every point in $[-1,1]$ (because if you add three points to a set of measure zero, the result still has measure zero), and therefore $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: o a set of measure zero is a singleton?

Comment: so when a bounted function is almost everywere continuous it's riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes, a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is almost everywhere continuous. A set of measure zero is a set that can be covered by countably many intervals with arbitrarily small positive length. More formally definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set#Definition

Comment: Alright thank you

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have that theorem available, so an alternate solution would be use the Riemann sum definition, with a partition of $[-1,1]$ that puts the points -1, 0, and 1 in very narrow rectangles, say $[-1,-1+\epsilon]$, $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, and $[1-\epsilon, 1]$.

Comment: @Bungo, no need for $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$.

Comment: @Philipp Ah, you're right, for some reason I was thinking that we only knew that $f$ was integrable on $[a,b]$ where $[a,b] \subseteq (-1,0)$ or $[a,b] \subseteq (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and *Riemann*-integrable on $[a,b]$ where $-1<a<0<b<1$.

$f$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$ so there must exist the following supremum und infimum $$M_a=M_b:=\sup\{f(x)~|~x\in [-1,1]\},$$ $$m_a=m_b:=\inf\{f(x)~|~x\in [-1,1]\}.$$

Let be $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary chosen. We now have to choose $a$ and $b$ such that they are sufficiently close to $-1$ and $1$ respectively. Let be $a+1<\frac{\epsilon}{3(M_a-m_a)}$ and $1-b<\frac{\epsilon}{3(M_b-m_b)}$. Consider the equidistant partition $P_n$ of $[a,b]$,
$$P_n:=\{a, a+\frac{b-a}{n}, a+2\frac{b-a}{n}, \cdots,a+(n-1)\frac{b-a}{n},b\}.$$

Let be $$M_i:=\sup\{f(x)~|~x\in [a+i\frac{b-a}{n},a+(i+1)\frac{b-a}{n}]\}$$
and
$$m_i:=\inf\{f(x)~|~x\in [a+i\frac{b-a}{n},a+(i+1)\frac{b-a}{n}]\}.$$

Then we know that for an arbitrary small $\frac{\epsilon}{3}>0$ there exists a $n_0$ such that every partition $P_n$ with a higher refinement than $P_{n_0}$ satisfies $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(M_i-m_i)\frac{b-a}{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ (This is the definition of the *Riemann*-integrability). Now we extend our interval $[a,b]$ to $[-1,1]$ such that our partition $P_n$ becomes
$$P_n:=\{-1,a, a+\frac{b-a}{n}, a+2\frac{b-a}{n}, \cdots,a+(n-1)\frac{b-a}{n},b,1\}.$$
Now the sum of the upper and lower *Darboux*-sums gets two more summands:
$$(M_a-m_a)\frac{\epsilon}{3(M_a-m_a)}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(M_i-m_i)\frac{b-a}{n}+(M_b-m_b)\frac{\epsilon}{3(M_b-m_b)}<\epsilon.$$
Hence, $f$ is *Riemann*-integrable on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: How you become a+1< and 1-b< at the beginning? i can't see why?

Comment: @mathmath, we must choose $a$ and $b$ sufficiently close to the bounds $-1$ and $1$, respectively. Hence, we set $|a-(-1)|=a+1<\epsilon'$ and $|b-1|=1-b<\epsilon'$ for a "very small" $\epsilon' >0$. To arrive at the desired result, *UpperSum* - *LowerSum* <$\epsilon$, we set $\epsilon':=\frac{\epsilon}{3(M_a-m_a)}$.

Comment: @mathmath, it's basically what Bungo said in his comment when he gave the advise to put $-1$ and $1$ in very narrow rectangles.

Comment: i can't understand why  you take a maximum and minimum but you write two times the same Ma and Mb are defined the same way?

Comment: @mathmath, yes that is correct. $M_a$ and $M_b$ are the same (so are $m_a$ and $m_b$). By using those indices I just wanted to stress that the two additional summands in the sum of the upper and lower Darboux sums come from $a$ and $b$ respectively. Maybe this was a bit confusing. I will edit my answer regarding this issue.